# QTabWidget put in the Central Widget of QMainWindow is stretching too much and covers the menu bar

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

Thats it a QtabWidget is put into the Central Widget of QMainWindow and it is stretching too much and covers the menu bar. At least I don't see anything wrong with making the layout and it is quite straightforward but it is not working for me. I know the import sucks :) I am using the latest PyQt5 for Windows. Any ideas?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setBaseSize(800, 600)
    self.controllerMonitors = []
    self.setWindowTitle("Window")
    sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 450))

    #--------
    # Menu
    #--------
    self.menuBar = QMenuBar(self)
    self.menuBar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))

    self.menu = QMenu(self.menuBar)
    self.menu.setTitle("Файл")

    self.actionSettings = QAction(self)
    self.actionSettings.setText("Настройки")
    self.actionExit = QAction(self)
    self.actionExit.setText("Изход")

    self.menu.addAction(self.actionSettings)
    self.menu.addAction(self.actionExit)

    self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
    self.menu.addAction(self.actionSettings)
    self.menu.addAction(self.actionExit)

    self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

    #---------
    # Toolbar
    #---------
    # self.mainToolBar = QToolBar(self)
    # self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
    # self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)

    #----------------
    # Central widget
    #----------------
    centralWidget = QWidget(self)
    centralWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
    centralWidget.setLayout(centralWidgetLayout)

    # sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    # sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    # sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
    # sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(centralWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    # centralWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
    centralWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.NoContextMenu)

    tabContainer = QTabWidget(centralWidget)

    tab1 = QWidget(tabContainer)
    te = QTextEdit(tab1)
    tab1layout = QVBoxLayout(tab1)
    tab1.setLayout(tab1layout)
    tab1layout.addWidget(te)

    tabContainer.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
    tabContainer.setCurrentIndex(0)
    centralWidgetLayout.addWidget(tabContainer)

    self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
```

And the main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


from MainWindow import MainWindow


def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the tab-widget: it's with the menu-bar.

The [QMainWindow class](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) already has a [built-in method](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) for creating a men-bar, so you don't need to create one yourself. (The reason why the menu-bar in your example is covered by the tab-widget is because you did not add it to a layout).

The set-up code for the menu in your example can be simplified to this:

```
    #--------
    # Menu
    #--------

    self.menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("Файл")
    self.actionSettings = self.menu.addAction("Настройки")
    self.actionExit = self.menu.addAction("Изход")
    self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

    #---------
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I didn't notice that somehow.